# Android mobile app is not listed in store for Galaxy Note 4

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-manifest, phonegap-build

App is not listed in store for Galaxy Note 4 device.
App is also limited for smartphone devices.
Please see my compatible screens list for mobile apps

```
    <supports-screens
android:largeScreens="false"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:resizeable="false"
android:anyDensity="false"
/>
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
     <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
```

I have also added the below detailed tags for some large devices.
[ support for Xperia Z, Galaxy S4 and HTC One ]

```
 <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="normal" /> 
    <screen android:screenDensity="480" android:screenSize="large" />
```

I tried with some higher values of screenDensity but it doesn't help.

Comment: I would recommend removing `<compatible-screens>` entirely. Why do you have it there in the first place?

Comment: @CommonsWare - Without specifying the <compatible-screens> I guess the app will be listed in all tablet devices also.... I need to limit the app for smartphones..

Comment: Your `<compatible-screens>` element does not "limit the app for smartphones". Many tablets are `large`. If you want to "limit the app for smartphones", then remove `large` from `<compatible-screens>` and live with the fact that you will not support "phablets" either.

Comment: @CommonsWare - is the App not listing issue kind of "android:screenDensity" support issue.. plz advise

Answer (score 0):

1. change both value to true.

   android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"

and clear your device google play cached data and try to search ,hope this will help you.